# Speaker Recognition API - Enrollment - Bad Request

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-cognitive-services

I have a newbie in development and I have been consuming azure speaker recognition. So far, I have been able to get the verification phrases, also been able to record .wav file through recorderjs and verifies profile successfully. Now the issue is I am unable to enroll the profile.

Following is my code

```
using (var content = new ByteArrayContent(body))
{
  content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(contentType);
  response = await client.PostAsync(uri, content);
}
```

In body, i am sending the stream as:

```
byte[] body= System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
```

I am getting a bad request in response. Can someone guide me how to get a response? Thanks.

EDIT: I am using azure's speaker recognition service. In the Speaker verification's enrollment phase, i am facing the aboveissue

Comment: Have you tried  Cognitive Services Speech SDK sample code  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/how-to-recognize-speech-csharp#continuous-speech-recognition-from-a-file

Comment: I am talking about speaker recognition. Not speech SDK

Comment: @SanaWaseem, add more details about you complete implementation of this call because here we don't even know which endpoint you are calling

Comment: The Speaker Recognition API (https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563309b6778daf02acc0a508/operations/5645c3271984551c84ec6797) requires that the `contentType` be either `application/octet-stream` or `multipart/form-data`.  It also requires that the audio file be a particular format (PCM 16KHz 16-bit mono).  Can you check those?

Comment: @SanaWaseem Did you solve your problem?

Comment: @ctrash -> I had been using the correct content type. Can you tell me how to send the audio part?

Comment: @AbdulMuheet Nope,